# Multiple dependent drop downs on jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to fill 2nd drop-down options on basis of 1st drop-down selection. 
Let say I am having 1 drop-down with options {India, South Africa, USA}
If I select India then 2nd drop-down must show {Rajasthan, MP, HP, UP...} 
and likewise others.

Here the values are static so resides on jsp only, but on the selection from both I have to perform filter condition in the back-end.

How can I do it with javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want something like this:

```js
var citiesByState = {
  USA: ["NY", "NJ"],
  Singapore: ["taas", "naas"],
  India: ["Rajasthan", "MP", "HP", "UP"]
}

function makeSubmenu(value) {
  if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var citiesOptions = "";
    for (cityId in citiesByState[value]) {
      citiesOptions += "<option>" + citiesByState[value][cityId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = citiesOptions;
  }
}

function resetSelection() {
  document.getElementById("countrySelect").selectedIndex = 0;
  document.getElementById("citySelect").selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

```html
<body onload="resetSelection()">
  <select id="countrySelect" size="1" onchange="makeSubmenu(this.value)">
    <option></option>
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>Singapore</option>
    <option>India</option>
  </select>
  <select id="citySelect" size="1">
    <option></option>
  </select>
</body>
```

> Note: The options you add in HTML like **India** must have same name and same cases(casesensitive) in JavaScript array like **India:** ["Rajasthan", "MP", "HP", "UP"]

Comment: So if that helped you and you are satisfied. Accept the Answer.

Comment: I want to know how can we do it in jquery?

Comment: Why do you need JQuery to do it? JavaScript is more lightweight and more convenient.